# What is the minimum size of any exFAT volume?

Tags: partitioning, exfat

I'm trying to create a partition of 20GB size exFAT filesystem, but no partitioning software allows me (even Windows Disk Management). With 40GB it allows me, so I presume there is a minimum size for an exFAT partition. Somebody can reference any documentation explaining more about this?

Comment: Just now I successfully format 1MiB (1048576 bytes) partition into exFAT file system using build-in `diskpart` and `format` command line utilities.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10, there was no problem formatting a 16 GB flash drive as exFAT. Admittedly, this is *not* a direct answer to your question, but at least it narrows the issue to either HDD vs. flash USB drive, or perhaps Windows version (which you did not state).

[image]

You might try to format using another version of Windows. exFAT is an MS proprietary format, so third-party tools might not work as well. Have you tried the tools at [AlternativeTo](http://alternativeto.net/browse/search?q=format)?

Comment: "Admittedly, this is not a direct answer to your question" Then why have you not posted it as a comment?

Comment: I'm using a SSD drive which has GPT partition table and already has partitions on it. Using Windows 10.

Comment: @ Xavierjazz, Can't put an image in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `mkexfatfs` utility on (Arch)Linux I can format a 84 KiB (86,016 bytes) partition with exFAT, but for 83 KiB (84,992 bytes) the utility errors out (`ERROR: too small device (83 KB)`).

On Windows I can't go below 1 MiB, because `diskpart` seems to only accept size arguments in MiB.